Import existing resource into CloudFormation stack (SAM)
We have a VPC Endpoint that was setup manually through the AWS console and we'd like to be managed through CloudFormation. We can't just create a new one, because the Endpoint is used to connect to a third-party EndpointService and they would need to approve a new one. So our only option is to import the resource.
We're using SAM, the AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 transform, so we can't just follow the standard instructions. Is there any way to do this import? I was thinking if we could apply the transform then I'd have a vanilla CloudFormation template in hand, and could then follow the existing instructions, but no luck so far.

were you able to achieve this ?
